# calling view ids in shared classe - android

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

Suppose I have several activities that all inherits from a same `BaseActivity`. I want to initialize some `drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);`. Each activity relies on some view as such

...#custom layout

When I put `drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);`
 in each activity, `drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);` in `BaseActivity`,I get some `NullPointerException`. 
Is there a way to get the view that was instantiated in some activity that inherits from `CustomActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can is the following. Let's call `someMethod` the protected method where you set `drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` in the `BaseActivity`. Now, in some of the custom activities, call in the `onCreate` method `someMethod` where

```
protected void someMethod(){
        super.someMethod();
    }
```